# ssh works only in LAN

Tags: openssh

I have two computers A and B, and I have installed openssh-server on A. I have successfully tried ssh to localhost on A, and also ssh to A from B, when A and B are connected to the same home router. However I would also like to connect to A outside my home router. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to forward port 22 of your router to your internal target.